# How to save a large array in txt file in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have 2D array:

```
import numpy as np

output = np.array([1,1,6])*np.arange(6)[:,None]+1

output
Out[32]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  7],
       [ 3,  3, 13],
       [ 4,  4, 19],
       [ 5,  5, 25],
       [ 6,  6, 31]])
```

I tried to use   `np.savetxt('file1.txt', output, fmt='%10d')`
i have got the result in one line only

How can I save it in  txt file  simillar to :

```
        x   y    z 
        1   1    1
        2   2    7
        3   3   13
        4   4   19
        5   5   25
        6   6   31
```

3  separate columns, each column  has name (x,y,z)

**Please note:** the original array too large (40000000 rows and 3 columns),   I am using Python 3.6
      I have tried the solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508633/write-a-2d-array-to-a-text-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685265/how-to-write-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-text-file) but, it does not work with me

Comment: In what ways do those solutions fail?

Comment: 40mio*3*3 characters for the data and spacing are roughly 350mb assuming 1 byter per character - thats not a too big file.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: but if we use text, it uses separators (tab and new line), and some data (e.g. floats) can use ~10-20 digits.

Comment: it is large but not big

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sure, his demodata are ints in range below 99 though and I rounded up ;) just trying to get a feel about his problem

Comment: @PatrickArtner: in case it is 0-99 uniformly, it is ~ 1.044 GiB.

Comment: "it does not work with me" **how** does it not work? I didn't downvote, but please read [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: I have got the result in one line, not in columns

Comment: I can save the array in txt file, but, it appears in one line not  organized   in rows and  columns similar above

Comment: You should tell `np.savetxt(...)` to use windows-style-newlines, by default it uses unix-style-ones and your editor is probably not smart enough to show those correctly as newlines. See answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I overlooked the %10d and used 3chars optimistically. You are far closer to the filesize - thanks for making me think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noor, let me guess - you are using windows notepad to view the file?

I use Notepad++ which is smart enough to understand Unix-style-Lineendings which are used (by default) when creating files by `np.savetxt()` even when operated under windows.

You might want to explicitly specify `newline="\r\n"` when calling `savetxt`.

```
np.savetxt('file1.txt', output, fmt='%10d' ,header= "       x          y          z", newline="\r\n")
```

Doku: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

---

I am not sure about your data, but this:

```
import numpy as np

output = np.array([1,1,6])*np.arange(60)[:,None]+1

print(output)


np.savetxt('file1.txt', output, fmt='%10d' ,header= "       x          y          z")
```

Produces this output:

```
#        x          y          z
         1          1          1
         2          2          7
         3          3         13 
       === snipped a few lines ===
        58         58        343
        59         59        349
        60         60        355
```

for me.

- for np.arange(1000000) its about 32MB big and similarly formatted...
- for np.arange(10000000) its about 322MB big and similarly formatted...

[willem-van-onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) 1+Gb was far closer.

I did not account for the spacing of fixed 10 chars per number, my bad.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick Artner, you are right, Notepad++, and  EmEditor, both of them   display the array in columns and rows

Comment: @Noor - specify the newline and windows style one are used- wich adds 40.000.000 bytes to your overall file size ;)